# Can a Java applet create a new folder on the client's machine?

Tags: java, file, applet, directory

If an applet is running in the browser, can it create folders or files on the client machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the applet must be [signed](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html).

A lot of manufactures download manager works like this.